# Loop through model and build SqlCommand obj

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, loops, model, ado.net

I have an MVC3 application and I want to pass my model to a method which builds a command object. The reason being that I have lots of methods with command objects and I want the code to be better written.

```
private static SqlCommand CommandObj(vw_UserManager_Model model)
{
    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand();
    command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;   


    foreach (var item in model)
    {
        switch (property.PropertyType.Name)
        {
            case "String":
                command.Parameters.Add("@" + property.Name, SqlDbType.VarChar).SqlValue = property;
                break;
            case "Guid":
                command.Parameters.Add("@" + property.Name, SqlDbType.UniqueIdentifier).SqlValue = property;
                break;
            case "Int32":
                command.Parameters.Add("@" + property.Name, SqlDbType.Int).SqlValue = property;
                break;
            case "Boolean":
                //switch (property.Name.FirstOrDefault())
                //{
                //    case true:
                //        command.Parameters.Add("@isactive", SqlDbType.Bit).SqlValue = 1;
                //        command.Parameters.Add("@isapproved", SqlDbType.Bit).SqlValue = 1;
                //        break;
                //    case false:
                //        command.Parameters.Add("@isactive", SqlDbType.Bit).SqlValue = 0;
                //        command.Parameters.Add("@isapproved", SqlDbType.Bit).SqlValue = 0;
                //        break;
                //}
                break;
        }
    }

    return command;
}
```

Currently this code won't compile because I can't enumerate through my model like this. What I want to do is loop through each item in the model and do a switch statement to build the correct dbType parameter.

Anyone have suggestions for how to change this code?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully I understood your question. Seems like you may be trying to do something like this. Here's my model class:

```
public class Person
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
    public bool Married { get; set; }
}
```

Here's the code that loops through the model properties:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Person person = new Person();
    var modelProperties = person.GetType().GetProperties();

    foreach (var property in modelProperties)
    {
        switch (property.PropertyType.Name)
        {
            case "String":
                Console.WriteLine("Property {0} is a string", property.Name);
                break;
            case "Int32":
                Console.WriteLine("Property {0} is an int", property.Name);
                break;
            case "Boolean":
                Console.WriteLine("Property {0} is a boolean", property.Name);
                break;
            default:
                Console.WriteLine("Type unknown!");
                break;
        }
    }
```

Hope this helps.